# I want to scrape a table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am new to stackoverflow.

I am trying to scrape a the table which comes under the heading "Import VAT and excise" from this website for the commodity code"1704906500". I know for sure that the table will fall under "Import VAT and excise" . I have several commodity codes and I will be looping through all the codes. The problem here is I am not able to point to the table under "Import VAT and excise " for scraping.

Please advice?

Weblink
[Scraping Webpage](https://www.trade-tariff.service.gov.uk/commodities/1704906500?currency=GBP#import)

[Screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d72eP.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
comCode="1704906500"
url = "https://www.trade-tariff.service.gov.uk/commodities/"+comCode+ "?currency=GBP#import"
url_request = requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(url_request, "lxml")

for header in soup.find_all('h3', text=re.compile('Import VAT and excise')):
    nextNode = header
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "h3":
                break
            print((nextNode))
            #comm_table = pd.read_html(nextNode.text, attrs = {"table class":"small-table measures govuk-table"} )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. It would good if you could describe what is the problem/error and what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I suppose that on the page the h3 element with id = vat_excise you want to scrape the table below. But please be specific, tell us what you have tried and what is the error.

Comment: Hi, means you want only the last table rite? is the table sequence fix?

Comment: I don't for each commodity code that I search this table will appear as the  last table. .No the table sequence is not fixed. All I know is this table will fall under the heading "Import VAT and excise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.find_next('table')` based on the selection of your heading:

```
soup.find('h3', text=re.compile('Import VAT and excise')).find_next('table')
```

or as alternative with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select_one('h3:-soup-contains("Import VAT and excise")').find_next('table')
```

##### Example

Iterate over a list of `comCodes` and concat all the tables to one dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
comCode=["1704906500"]

data = []

for c in comCode:
    url = f'https://www.trade-tariff.service.gov.uk/commodities/{c}?currency=GBP#import'
    soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    data.append(pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('h3:-soup-contains("Import VAT and excise")').find_next('table')))[0])

pd.concat(data)
```